# Getting wrong format response entity data

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data, resttemplate

Getting the wrong response data while using resttemplate.postEntity()

[image]

Comment: share the relevant code with details so that others can understand the issue

Comment: It seems that you got a HTTP status code `302` in your garbled response, but I don't know why if you don't provide more code about this issue!